# statement that can be validly inferred from the proposition - All animals are wild

Tags: logic

Which one of the following can be validly inferred from the proposition - "All animals are  wild" ?

Options

1. Some animals are wild.
2. Some animals are not wild.
3. No animals are wild.
4. No non-animals are wild.

I think some animals are wild can mean all animals are wild, isn't? I guess the correct answer is option 1.

source:
http://netexam.pmgurus.com/ugc-net-online-questions.aspx?q=UGC-NTA-NET-PAPER-1-solved-answer-paper-22-DECEMBER-2018-SHIFT1&gid=180&h=1&QID=12771&Qno=23

Comment: You are correct. Always when you see a propositon with the words "some ... are", interpret that as "there is at least one ... so that ... "

Comment: None of the above, unfortunately. You're right that option 1 is the closest, but inferring that some animals are wild implicitly assumes some animals exist, which need not be true for the statement "all animals are wild" to be correct.

Comment: @TheoBendit - but animals exist...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA In actuality, yes they do. Also, in actuality, not all animals are wild, so I would be very hesitant about inferring truths from actuality. In fact, from the contradiction of the hypothesis with the actual fact that some animals are not wild, you could derive all four possibilities! The point is, in an introductory course in propositional logic, while dealing with real things helps students get to grips with the logic, it's a really bad idea to allow them to add in hypotheses that they believe are actually true.

Comment: @TheoBendit - correct... what I mean is that at the "elemenatry level" of the above question, I think taht can be misleading to invoke the subtleties of "empty domains" ... :-)